# How to best inspect and transform every cell in a sql server table when copying it to another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, copy, transform

I have a series of tables that I have to move to another database. In the process of moving them, I need to inspect every cell and if it has a specific value, null that cell.

I have table containing meta data with attributes which point to each cell, and a list of bad values that must be removed from the original tables.

For example I have the following table

```
TABLE1
ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
   7    |   10     |   DK     |
   83   |   -7     |          |
   16   |   0      |   True   |
```

Then the meta table has

```
Tablename | Column |  Bad Value 1 | Bad Value 2 |
  TABLE1  |ColumnC |      DK      |    BOL      |
  TABLE1  |ColumnA |      -99     |    -1       |
  TABLE1  |ColumnB |      -1      |     -7      |
```

In the copied and transformed TABLE1 I would have

```
TABLE1
ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
   7    |   10     |   NULL   |
   83   |   NULL   |          |
   16   |   0      |   True   |
```

I want to understand what is going to be the best way to do this. I have considered writing a function that gets called for each cell. It would be passed the meta information needed to lookup the cell in the meta "bad values" table, and the current value of the cell, then would return the cell value or NULL, depending on whether or not the cell matched any of the corresponding bad values.

If I go this route, I could apply this at the point at which I read the value from the original table, write the value to the new table, or after copying, run a separate process that would change the value in the copied table.

I will need to repeat the process periodically (weekly).

Any advice you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a cursor for this, and use Dynamic SQL.  I don't think you'll find anyone here that will code the whole  thing for you, but here are some points for consideration.

- Make a "master" table that has all your tables to copy.  I'm assuming it will be possible to have a table that doesn't need a substitution at some point.  This will allow you to modify the process easily.  Suggested structure would be something like `Database, Schema, Table, Active` with `Active` being a bit you can toggle.
- Using Dynamic SQL, build an `INSERT` statement for each table.  Get your "bad" values from the table to populate a `CASE` for those fields.  So, something like `CASE WHEN ColumnC = 'DK' OR ColumnC = 'BOL' THEN NULL ELSE ColumnC as ColumnC`.  This will update the value "in transit" so you don't alter your existing DB but your target has the desired changes.
- You will need to either have an entry for every column in the affected tables, have a separate "master" table for your columns per table, or query the system tables to get a list of fields to be copied.  You can't just do a `SELECT *` if you need to do a `CASE` statement.

Comment: A couple of the tables have 1000+ columns. With a case statement for every column, is it possible I would bump up against a query string limit?

Comment: Not sure.  You have a really problematic structure, then.  I can't think of a reason you would need a 1000 field table unless there were a DBA you were trying to punish from crimes in a previous life.

Comment: One table represents a 50 page medical health questionnaire with 1000+ questions

Comment: @user - There are better ways to do that, such as a table with triple key of `UserId, TestId, AnswerID`.  It's a lot easier to process millions of rows three fields wide than thousands of rows thousands of fields wide.  None of your rows will fit on a page, so you have  tons of fragmentation and other issues from that.

Comment: And, I really appreciate that you took the time to answer the question in the first place JNK! I was just wondering if anyone has faced a similar ordeal.

Comment: Yes, an EAV table. That is what we are moving to, but this is a legacy system

Comment: @user - I think if anyone has a similar structure they are not likely to admit it here :)  IMO your top priority should be fixing your structure.  It will make pretty much everything else run faster.  Currently there's no way to search your table effectively, since you would need either insanely wide indexes (and these are limited by the engine) or a lot of narrow indexes that are not very useful.  Look into a composite key!